# what is difference between platform.js and plusone.js of google api?

Tags: javascript, scripting, google-api

what is difference between platform.js and plusone.js of google api.

I get an error on console if i used plusone.js. Error is

> "plusone.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined".

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 3):

*platform.js* is Google's library for accessing the Google Plus API.

*plusone.js* is an old library Google provided for adding a +1 button to a page. [It has been superseded](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) by *platform.js*.